when should i use .load() function on office js objects?
when should i use .load() on powerpoint API objects ?? is it when i want to load their properties. for example slide object has the following properties
context
The request context associated with the object. This connects the add-in's process to the Office host application's process.
id
Gets the unique ID of the slide.
layout
Gets the layout of the slide.
shapes
Returns a collection of shapes in the slide.
slideMaster
Gets the SlideMaster object that represents the slide's default content.
tags
Returns a collection of tags in the slide.
If i want to access the shapes of the slide, should i first do slide.load("shapes") and when i console.log(slide.shapes), then it should log out the slides right ??
I wanted to understand when to use the .load() and when it is not necessary.

See load() or the book Building Office Add-ins.
